# Upload Magento 1 Extension to Marketplace

Tags: module, extensions, marketplace

I'm uploading a Magento 1 extension to the Marketplace and I get the following error.

[image: The archive "Mage1.tgz" does not follow Magento conventions.]

I included the `"package.xml"` file in the root of my directory and got that error.

It was possible to get the approval from Magento and actually have the extension published if I upload a `.tgz` with *only* the `package.xml` file inside, but I'm never asked for the actual code of my extension.

What is it supposed to be inside the package `.tgz` file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create this with the help of Magento

> System > Magento Connect > Package Extensions

[This tutorial how this do it](https://www.apptha.com/blog/how-to-create-an-extension-package-file-in-magento/)